# Can somebody tell why I'm getting this URL is crawled more than other pages?

Tags: wordpress, web, web-crawler, malware-detection

I checked the web stats of my site and seeing specific URL getting more hits than the other.

I just scan the site trying to find out the location but file not exist.

{"version":"1.0","provider_name":"Pragmatic Web Media","provider_url":"https://pragmaticwebmedia.com","title":"How to Add ClickTag in HTML5?","type":"rich","width":600,"height":338,"html":"How to Add ClickTag in HTML5?</a></blockquote>\n\n1e3)g=1e3;else if(~~g<200)g=200;f.height=g}if(\"link\"===d.message)if(h=b.createElement(\"a\"),i=b.createElement(\"a\"),h.href=f.getAttribute(\"src\"),i.href=d.value,i.host===h.host)if(b.activeElement===f)a.top.location.href=d.value}else;}},d)a.addEventListener(\"message\",a.wp.receiveEmbedMessage,!1),b.addEventListener(\"DOMContentLoaded\",c,!1),a.addEventListener(\"load\",c,!1)}(window,document);\n\/\/-->\n</script></iframe>","thumbnail_url":"https://pragmaticwebmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Clicktag-768x432-768x432.jpg","thumbnail_width":600,"thumbnail_height":338}

Need to understand what that means?. Is this malware injection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have used wordpress theme or plugins created by 'Pragmatic Web Media', to avoid ads and all you must get your own wordpress theme from scratch.

Comment: Pragmatic Web Media is my site. I have not created any theme or plugin.

Comment: disable used plugins and check